# Why my jquery code wont work if with ID but Class

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

I have html code like this.

```
<input onkeyup="ave()" type="text" name="1" class = "ave" style="width: 60px"></td>
<input onkeyup="ave()" type="text" name="2" class = "ave" style="width: 60px"></td>
<input onkeyup="ave()" type="text" name="3" class = "ave" style="width: 60px"></td>
```

The jQuery like this

```
function ave(){

   $('.ave').keyup(function(){
      var sum = 0;
      var ave = 0;
      $('.ave').each(function(){
        sum += +$(this).val();
      });
      var ave  = sum/3;
      $('.total').val(ave.toFixed(2));
   });
}
```

If I change 'class' to 'ID' and `$('.ave')` to `$('#ave')` the code won't work!

Comment: ***ID should always be unique***. It wont work for second element if there are duplicate IDs. Using class is the solution for this problem

Comment: Where is the php part?

Comment: @guradio, but if the id unique it wont be counted, you can see my code is for count them all that have same class and average it

Comment: @epodax i dont use php code for this.

Comment: any specific reason that you want to make this code workable with IDs?

Comment: @bayuwibisana Then why is your question tagged with PHP

Comment: @vijayP  i want add variable on jquery selector, like $('#ave.'+var).

Comment: @vijayP and the variable is filled by looping that have value 0 - 20

Comment: @Epodax sorry i type php too often, how to edit the tag ?

Comment: Press the "Edit" button on your question and remove the tag from there.

Comment: @Epodax, thanks, i just join few minutes ago.

Answer (score 2):

IDs are unique within a HTML document,Id can be used only one time in a document but classes can be used multiple times within the same document. IDs usually identify a unique item within your document where as classes help apply a common style to multiple items across the page. Hence for your problem can not use Id.

Comment: i will add variable on id so it will become like this id = 'var<?= $var ?>', so there is wot be duplicate ID's

Comment: But in your question... there is no such information.

Comment: yeah it will become looong question if i put it in there, but thanks anyway you are so helpful.

Answer (score 1):

***ID should always be unique***.

> Using class is the solution for this problem

Comment: but if the id unique it wont be counted, you can see my code is for count them all that have same class and average it

Comment: use `this` to refer to current input

Answer (score 1):

Please have a look at below code. You can refer this code and can check how we are calculating the average

```js
  
  function ave(){
    var sum = 0;
    var ave = 0;
    
    $('.myTextboxContainer input').each(function(){
        if(!isNaN($(this).val()))
          sum += +$(this).val();
    });
    ave  = sum/$('.myTextboxContainer input').length;
    $('.total').val(ave.toFixed(2));
  }
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.11.0/jquery.min.js"></script>

<table class="myTextboxContainer">
  <tr>
  <td><input onkeyup="ave()" type="text" name="1" id = "ave1" style="width: 60px"></td>
  <td><input onkeyup="ave()" type="text" name="2" id = "ave2" style="width: 60px"></td>
  <td><input onkeyup="ave()" type="text" name="3" id = "ave3" style="width: 60px"></td>
  </tr>
</table>  

<div>
  Average is : <input  type="text" class="total"></span>
</div>
```

Comment: my code is currently running, but if i add variable to $('.ave.'+count), which 'count' is have looped , it wont work, i have been searching all day and people said jquery selector must be id like $('#ave.'+count);

Comment: `$('#ave.'+count);`. Here i can see a dot after `#ave`. This is invalid `id`. I can't have like `<input id="mytext.1"`. This is incorrect `id` given to textbox. Valid id can be in this case are `<input id="mytext1"` Or `<input id="mytext_1"`

Comment: and i will add some class become class = 'ave<?=$ave?>' which $ave have been looped

Comment: so i can do it if i went like this `$('.ave'+count)` ? but when i alert it, [object] [Object] always become the output

Comment: really sorry @bayuwibisana; but i couldn't able to visualize your situation. Can its possible for you to post some more code and what output you are looking for from it?

Comment: oke you know i have 3 input, and 1 for the average.
i looped that 3 input so i have many line that have that four input.
i use `$variable++` for put it in `class = 'var<?=$variable'?>`
so i wont have duplicate right ?

now went to Jquery.
from jquery i want to do the same thing, but i dont understand how to place looped variable to squery selector.

Answer (score 1):

In your code you are binding same element twice. `onkeyup="ave()"` and inside the function   `$('.ave').keyup(function()` here javascript first call your function **ave()** but there is one more time binding keyup object..

1. So the first keyup goes to function ave() and bind **.ave** with keyup event.
2. On second keyup is call same **ave()** then perform jquery keyup bind from **first keyup** then so the **.each(function(){** executes twice then again element bind
3. The third and other keyup will make complex binding 4 times executes keyup and so on.

**Best practice**

```
 <input onkeyup="ave()" type="text" name="1" class = "ave" style="width: 60px"></td>
    <input onkeyup="ave()" type="text" name="2" class = "ave" style="width: 60px"></td>
    <input onkeyup="ave()" type="text" name="3" class = "ave" style="width: 60px"></td>
```

**Javascript**

```
function ave(){
      var sum = 0;
      var ave = 0;
      $('.ave').each(function(){
        sum += +$(this).val();
      });
      var ave  = sum/3;
      $('.total').val(ave.toFixed(2));
}
```

[FiDDLE DEMO](https://jsfiddle.net/sy2pdk7z/2/)